# How to read these graphs and what are they called?

Tags: proteins

How does one interpret/read the following graph ([found here](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/entry/search/index?uniprot_accession:(P41160%20OR%20P41159))) as well as on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptin) or

[image: PDB graph]

What are these called?

Comment: According to your first link, this is from an x-ray diffraction image of human obesity protein, or leptin. It's called a ribbon diagram (and maybe other things, not my area of expertise).

Comment: Well, I'd call them coordinate/arbitrary axes...if you're talking about the arrows at the bottom left ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depiction is a [ribbon diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_diagram) of a protein structure. It shows the protein backbone (alpha carbons and the peptide bonds) smoothed out to a continuous line. In certain areas where the protein adopts alpha-helices or beta-sheets, these are indicated by the elaborate spiral in your picture (alpha-helix) or a wide, flat arrow (beta-sheet; not present in your structure). These depictions are supposed to give you an idea of what the protein looks like.

I would assume the two arrows in the bottom to be two of the coordinate axes of the crystal since ribbon diagrams are typically obtained from crystal structures. However, I cannot know without additional information (e.g. in a footnote of a picture).